# My layout shows up differently on virtual and physical devices

Tags: android, xml

In Android Studio Preview and on my virtual device the layout looks how I want it to look. However, as soon as I put the .apk on my OnePlus 3 the items in my layout are out of place. It is a Constraint Layout since I feel like it is the easiest to use and until now I have never had problems with it. I have already tried to change the size of my ImageView layouts or change the relations between the items but nothing has worked so far.

activity_settings.xml:

```
<!-- Toolbar -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#FF5F58"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextColor="#FFF" />

<!-- Squat -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/borderImageView_squat"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/borderImageView_deadlift"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/borderImageView_bench"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/options_border" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/squatTextView"
    style="@style/StandardText"
    android:layout_width="50pt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
    android:text="Squat"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/borderImageView_squat"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/borderImageView_squat"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/borderImageView_squat" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/squatEditText"
    android:layout_width="50pt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_light"
    android:hint="-"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#FF5F58"
    android:textColorHint="#FF5F58"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/borderImageView_squat"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/borderImageView_squat"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/borderImageView_squat"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/squatTextView" />

<!-- Bench -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/borderImageView_bench"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/borderImageView_ohp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/borderImageView_squat"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/options_border" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/benchTextView"
    style="@style/StandardText"
    android:layout_width="50pt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
    android:text="Bench"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/borderImageView_bench"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/borderImageView_bench"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/borderImageView_bench" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/benchEditText"
    android:layout_width="50pt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_light"
    android:hint="-"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColorHint="#FF5F58"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#FF5F58"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/borderImageView_bench"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/borderImageView_bench"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/borderImageView_bench"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/benchTextView" />

<!-- Deadlift -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/borderImageView_deadlift"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/refreshValuesBtn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/borderImageView_ohp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/borderImageView_squat"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/options_border" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/deadliftTextView"
    style="@style/StandardText"
    android:layout_width="50pt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
    android:text="Deadlift"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/borderImageView_deadlift"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/borderImageView_deadlift"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/borderImageView_deadlift" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/deadliftEditText"
    android:layout_width="50pt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_light"
    android:hint="-"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColorHint="#FF5F58"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#FF5F58"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/borderImageView_deadlift"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/borderImageView_deadlift"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/borderImageView_deadlift"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/deadliftTextView" />


<!-- OHP -->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/borderImageView_ohp"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/refreshValuesBtn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/borderImageView_deadlift"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/borderImageView_bench"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/options_border" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ohpTextView"
    style="@style/StandardText"
    android:layout_width="50pt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_regular"
    android:text="OHP"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/borderImageView_ohp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/borderImageView_ohp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/borderImageView_ohp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ohpEditText"
    android:layout_width="50pt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/lato_light"
    android:hint="-"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColorHint="#FF5F58"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#FF5F58"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/borderImageView_ohp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/borderImageView_ohp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/borderImageView_ohp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ohpTextView" />

<!-- "SAVE" button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/refreshValuesBtn"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="40pt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="SAVE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Android Studio Preview Screenshot:
[image: how it should look]

Virtual Device Screenshot:
[image: how it should look]

OnePlus 3 with .apk Screenshot:
[image: how it looks]

Comment: you need to use Relative Layout or Grid layout as a child of Relative Layout which will be align to the center to the screent

Comment: You have not used your ConstraintLayout features properly. I mean you have given fixed widths and height in your image and text views so opening your view in any layout results in it being constant.. You must consider using match constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified width and height in dps, that's why the results are different.

1- Use wrap_content or match_parent for width and height.

2- There is no need for image views. use backgroundresource of edit text.

3- for text size, user textAppearance to get more accurate results on all different screen sizes.

If You want to use hardcoded dps, then create multiple values folder for different resolution, hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi.

Please understand the concept for pixels and densities.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Also use constraint layout properly.

**Cheers!! Simplicity is the best!**

Answer (score 0):

Also define a parent layout like RelativeLayout, LinearLayout or ConstraintsLayout.
If you want to display a grid, use the feature gridView :

https://www.raywenderlich.com/995-android-gridview-tutorial

i saw :

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/borderImageView_squat"
android:layout_width="136dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/borderImageView_deadlift"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/borderImageView_bench"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/options_border" />
```

but use instead :

```
android:background="@drawable/options_border"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the all correction, of course change it from your preferences :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Toolbar -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#FF5F58"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

<!-- Squat -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/user_select_parent_squat_bench"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_button_color_defined"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/squatTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Squat" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/squatEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="-"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FF5F58"
            android:textColorHint="#FF5F58" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_button_color_defined"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/benchTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Bench" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/benchEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="-"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FF5F58"
            android:textColorHint="#FF5F58" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/user_select_parent_deadlift_ohp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/user_select_parent_squat_bench"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_button_color_defined"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deadliftTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Deadlift" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/deadliftEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="-"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FF5F58"
            android:textColorHint="#FF5F58" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_button_color_defined"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OhpTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="OHP" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/OhpEditView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="-"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FF5F58"
            android:textColorHint="#FF5F58" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<!-- "SAVE" button -->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/refreshValuesBtn"
    android:layout_width="40pt"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/user_select_parent_deadlift_ohp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="SAVE" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your xml you are using `Constraint Layout`. You can find more from [official reference](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

Here i will show some work related to your needs. First you need to add guidelines that means hidden line to your constraint layout to seperate your widths & heights of `ConstraintLayout`.

**Step 1(Add Guideline)**

> You can add guideline via layout editor as well find below image. By clicking on small circle in line you can change line type to dp,percentage as well.

[image]

Here am using percentage guideline & mention orientation for horizontal & vertical.

Now your code look like below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Step2(Add views)**

Now add views and add constraints with guideline.. Let add first views.

[image]

Here you can adjust your view alignment & also check with different size of device it resize according to device size.

> **Note set your width & height to match contraints and in xml you will see 0dp.**

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_2" />
```

Now add other views as well. (TextView & edittext)..

> **Now align other views based on imageview set align left,right,top to imageview.**

[image]

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />
```

**Step 3(Add all other views)**

[image]

**Final Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView7" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView6" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView6"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Save"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline6" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```